# two IPython console sharing the same wrokspace

Tags: python, ipython

I am using IPython to do scientific computing. I would like to see the variables in different console. Is that possible to open two IPython console sharing the same workspace, that is, the variables in one python console can be accessed by another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You start an IPython kernel and then connect to that kernel with different consoles.

Here is the documentation how to create connect to the same kernel with multiple consoles: [Multiple Consoles](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/qtconsole.html#multiple-consoles)